# Book recommendations for Geometry

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like to know if there is a book on Geometry from a modern point of view which can guide me through the basics of the subject into more advanced graduate level material. I’m looking for a book on geometry that as closely resembles the books on Analysis by Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher in structure and presentation as possible because I really like those texts.

Do tell me about any other valuable sources that can help me with this

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Amann and Escher's book, but the classic introductory text to modern (algebraic) geometry is Hartshorne's book "[Algebraic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902449)". This requires a good background in commutative algebra and basic topology, but it is worthwhile. Other texts that come to mind would be Eisenbud and Harris' "[The Geometry of Schemes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986375)", Shafarevich's "[Basic Algebraic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642379559)", or Mumford's "[Red Book of Varieties and Schemes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/354063293X)". Also, though I'm not as familiar with it, I have heard that Ravi Vakil's book "[The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf)" (available for download online) is very good.

If you're interested more in differential geometry, perhaps Lee's "[Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954481)" might be a good place to start, but maybe others have better suggestions in this respect.

A more comprehensive list of texts can be found in the responses [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2446/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne).